# Unexpected results when using terms query on custom keyword field with special characters

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have an index with the following field:

```
myField: {
    type: "text",
    fields: {
        keyword: {
            type: "keyword",
            ignore_above: 256
        },
        keyword_lowercase: {
            type: "text",
            analyzer: "lowercase_keyword_analyzer",
            fielddata: true
        }
    },
    analyzer: "autocomplete_analyzer",
    search_analyzer: "autocomplete_search_analyzer"
},
```

Analyzers:

```
lowercase_keyword_analyzer: {
    filter: [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding"
    ],
    type: "custom",
    tokenizer: "keyword"
},
autocomplete_search_analyzer: {
    filter: [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding"
    ],
    type: "custom",
    tokenizer: "standard"
},
autocomplete_analyzer: {
    filter: [
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding",
        "autocomplete_edge_ngram"
    ],
    type: "custom",
    tokenizer: "standard"
}
```

I have a document with the value: L’OCCITANE

A MATCH query of:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
        {
            "match": {
                "myField.keyword_lowercase": {
                    "query": "l’occitane"
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Finds it, however A TERM query of:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
        {
            "term": {
                "myField.keyword_lowercase": {
                    "value": "l’occitane"
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Does not.  Weirdly if I change the apostrophe from the ’ that's in the document to ':

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
        {
            "term": {
                "myField.keyword_lowercase": {
                    "value": "l'occitane"
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

The term search now works. I find this issue with other words with special characters, as far as I understand the asciifolding filter should be preventing this.

Whats going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of hard to see but those are, as you said, two kinds of apostrophes. I'd say one is the `single quote`, the French one is the `apostrophe`.

Indexing both of them separately

```
POST mag/_doc
{"myField": "l'occitane"}

POST mag/_doc
{"myField":"l’occitane"}
```

and then aggregating by the *analyzed* keyword:

```
GET mag/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "by_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "myField.keyword_lowercase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```
"buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "l'occitane",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
```

which means that the asciifolding fiter converted the `apostrophe` to the `single-quote` and since the term query operates on exact values in the inverted index, you won't be able to query with the `apostrophe`. You'll need to go with

```
...
        {
          "term": {
            "myField.keyword_lowercase": {
              "value": "l'occitane"
            }
          }
        }
...
```

If you do want to apply a lowercase term query, you'll need to remove asciifolding or add another mapping field inside `myField` without the above mentioned asciifolding. That way, querying `myField.keyword_lowercase_no_ascii` **will** work with the apostrophes.

Comment: It makes sense to me that they are both tokenized as l'occitane, however shouldn't the terms query apply the same analyzer meaning both apostrophe and single quote are treated as the same search?

Comment: Both of the special chars will be indexed as the single quote, yes. But the `term` value will *not* be analyzed -- remember, you're looking for an `exact` term.

Comment: Ah so the TERM search doesn't analyze the query, that's annoying. Kind of the whole point of the filters. I want a keyword that is not case sensitive and handles special characters.  I guess a MATCH query with the lowercase_keyword_analyzer would active this?

Comment: came here after 3 hrs of banging head to the wall and the first line of this answer is the solution to my problem :|

Comment: It happens to the best of us. Hey BTW -- my Elasticsearch Handbook comes out soon and I think it'd bring you value. Do [let me know what you'd like to learn about](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) and I'll let you know when it's out. There might some some other moments of clarity for ya!